# Hide a specific date in php output

Tags: php

I am pulling a date from a database, but instead of having a null value when there is no specified date it fills in the date as "31/12/9999"

The code I have to display the date is:

```
<?=date('d/m/Y', strtotime($record[0]['due_date']))?>
```

Does anyone know how I can add to that so it does not display anything if the value is "31/12/9999"

Comment: What's the actual value of `$record[0]['due_date']`? `null` wouldn't produce this output.

Comment: The date will be the date in the column, it is either a correct date or "31/12/9999" so there are no null values in that column.

Comment: `if ($record[0]['due_date'] !== '31/12/9999') {}` ?

Comment: That doesn't work, it does not display anything.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. But splash's comment is then dead on. It's just a matter of a simple condition to wrap around your printing code.

Answer (score 0):

go to database and change field setting to allow null, it's better for you

Comment: The data is imported from a text file, the values in the text files are pre-populated. This is just to display information from the database, not to interact with it in any way.

Comment: then you can compare string, or date difference https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php